# jsonp callback function not getting called with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have scoured this site and elsewhere trying to solve the problem I am having with jsonp.  To start things off, here's the code that I have:

```
url =  "http://mydomain.com/return_json";

$.ajax({
    url: url, // + '?callback=?' --I realized this is not necessary with dataType: 'jsonp'
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        },
    success: function(dataWeGotViaJsonp){
        var text = '';
        var len = dataWeGotViaJsonp.length;
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
            item = dataWeGotViaJsonp[i];
            text += '<p>' + item + '</p>';
        }
        $('#action_target').html(text);
    }
});
```

On the sending side, the `/return_json` url is a Django site that is sending json data the following way:

```
def return_json(request):

    data = [{'testing': 'testing'}, {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}]

    return HttpResponse( json.dumps(data), content_type="application/javascript" )
```

As you can see in the JavaScript, I'm indescriminately dumping everything into the console on error.  Here is the output of that:

```
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"}
parsererror
Error: jQuery110207276483389928793_1377030169256 was not called
```

The 'net' area of firebug shows that the url was:
`http://mydomain.com/return_json?     callback=jQuery110209170565296948737_1377029879665&_=1377029879666`

It also shows that valid JSON is in the response.  It even has a JSON section with a pretty-fied output.  So, obviously my problem is that the jQuery auto-generated callback function is there, but not getting called.  I get the same result using the $.ajax and $.getJSON methods set up for jsonp.  The only thing I can think of at this point is that I'm supposed to wrap the json data in a function somehow on the sender's side, but I was under the impression that the receiver takes care of that.  If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

=================================UPDATE WITH FULL ANSWER========================

Hamish has the correct answer below, although it just needs two minor tweaks.  Here is how you can send data in JSONP format using Django:

```
def return_json(request):
#                      ^--------I didn't need a parameter in this situation
json_data = ["one", "two", "three"]

return render_to_response("uitest/jsonp_template.html", Context({
    'callback': request.GET.get('callback'),
    'json': mark_safe(json.dumps( json_data )),
#                ^------------------------------This keeps your JSON from getting mangled in 
#                                               URL                                                      
}), mimetype="application/javascript")
#^---------------------This closing parentheses was missing in Hamish's answer at the time
#                      of this writing.
```

Comment: JSONP does not return JSON. JSONP returns a function call, passing the JSON to it. Your response should be in the form of `jQuery1239823492834(YOUR JSON HERE);`, where you get the name of the function by using the `request` and getting the "callback" item. Then you build the response in the format I just mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `JSONP` response is actually a *script* response - something like:

```
callbackFunctionName([{'testing': 'testing'}, {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}]);
```

Create a template that returns a `application/javascript` response with a function call to function `request.GET.get('callback')` with the body of the JSON as the only argument.

Something like:

```
def return_jsonp(request, json_data)
    return render_to_response("jsonp_template.html", Context({
        'callback': request.GET.get('callback'),
        'json': json.dumps(json_data),
    }, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

Where `jsonp_template.html` is just:

```
{{ callback }}({{ json }});
```

Comment: Note that a whole template might be overkill, maybe just render from a string :)

Comment: Ah, so my suspicions were correct.  I need to format it with a function on the sender's side.  This is the first example I've seen for trying to do that in Django, so thank you for that.  It appears that you're missing a closing parentheses for `Context` in parameter 2.  When I add that in, I am still getting the same overall result, but instead of the JSON data in the response, it just has the jQuery random-name function sitting there.  Could I be missing something that is supposed to trigger it?

Comment: I forgot to notify you with the previous comment.

Comment: You should have the function with the body of the JSON - it's not really JSON anymore, at this point. Can you post the content that is sent back and the error response?

Comment: Sure, everything is the same, including the console errors/content.  The only difference is that under net, and the appropriate get request, it has the name of the function, `jQuery110206621304255184078_1377125326378`

Comment: Nevermind, Its working!  You were right about `mark_safe()`.  Thank you VERY much.  I wish I was worthy of upvoting your answer.  I am but a SO noob that can only offer gratitude.